# How about a DevDays Attendee badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Not that these events seem to need any more promotions given the rate they are selling out, but I'd think a badge for attendees of a DevDays event would definitely reflect people that are active members of the SO community.

Comment: I cant attend as it is my kids birthday. However a '10 today' badge would help ease the pain.

Comment: No. Absolutely not. No way! Not until i get my "name ends with a number" badge...

Comment: Well then, I want a "Name starts with a silent g" badge!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to go against the grain and say: **I think it's a good idea.**  (And no, I can't attend any)

The argument *against* it seems to focus around "I shouldn't have to pay for a badge" and "I don't have the opportunity to go, it's not fair."  Another one I suppose would be "Badges shouldn't be awarded for Real-Life Actions."

The arguments for?  Badges are meant to convey your contribution and interest to SO.  Contributing to a real-life (not-for-profit) extension of Stackoverflow, Dev Days goes along with that.  (1)

The Beta Badge fits against "Badges I don't have the opportunity to earn".  The Hacker Badge, and the few people who have earned it, fits against "Badges I don't have the opportunity to earn", and to a lesser extent "Badges shouldn't be awarded for Real-Life Actions."
As for "paying" for a badge - if you seriously go to DevDays just for a badge that's just sad.  And everyone saying "I shouldn't have to pay for a badge" is implying just that.  I *know* you wouldn't pay for it.  No one would.  So awarding it to people who paid isn't them buying a badge, it's rewarding people who have contributed to the community of SO - building better programmers.

You will not earn every badge, and it's **not unfair to limit you** by awarding badges to others who have contributed in a way you can't.

FWIW I still think a Founder/Developer badge is also fine.

(1) AFAIK Dev Days is not for profit, or at least not for much profit.  StackExchange is radically different.

Comment: Wait, people have earned the Hacker badge?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge  You think the guy who pulled this off http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001267.html doesn't deserve it?

Comment: DevDays has more to do with the new version of Fog Bugz than to Stack Overflow. If you notice Joel is planning on going to all of them.

Comment: The blog post says "it has yet to be awarded". Has this changed?

Comment: @Brad: Valid, I hadn't given much thought to that.

Answer (score 9):

I shouldn't have to pay for a badge

Comment: You wouldn't have to pay for it. There is no requirement to have any badges.

Comment: You have to pay the registration fee.

Comment: Let me clarify. Not having one of the badges isn't the end of the world. I am fairly certain I won't get every badge possible, what harm is it if someone else gets it?

For example, if you don't have the beta badge you are pretty much out of luck. Is that unfair too?

Answer (score 8):

A badge for attending isn't a bad idea at all - similar to the Beta badge in that it's a one-time deal and can't be earned if you miss it. Maybe I'd feel differently if I were unable to attend, but I don't think that it's necessary for all the badges to be winnable and/or no barrier to entry (i.e. no-cost).

I envision the badge could look something like this:

[image]

with the format being `devdays-[city]-[year]` so attendees can connect with others that went to the same conference. The color is tweakable - I only used a silver badge as the base for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I like the idea of tagging with the city and year.  That's a nice way to keep track of people you may have met.

Comment: @Mark Harrison - Of course the hard-core badge whores would have to travel around the country/world to collect them all.

Answer (score 3):

**Good for Building Community**

It would be a nice way to put a face to a user.

"Hey, I remember meeting this person...."

Answer (score 2):

How many people are going to ask this?

The answer has always been 'No'.

I don't expect that to change.

Comment: Is this a dupe question? I searched for a similar one before posting and didn't find one.

Comment: It's a duplicate *suggestion*. The idea been discussed one or two times, but not in a dedicated question.